# Unbinding NVIDIA USB controller in Fedora 32 as ASUS laptop would resume right after suspend

Tags: linux, usb, fedora, suspend, nvidia

My ASUS laptop was resuming immediately after suspending it. After going through the log files, I figured out that it was `Device 0000:01:00.2` that would fail to suspend. The logs are given below:

```
Jul 09 15:42:02 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ kernel: nvme nvme0: 8/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Jul 09 15:42:02 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ kernel: PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
Jul 09 15:42:02 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ kernel: PM: Device 0000:01:00.2 failed to suspend async: error -110
Jul 09 15:42:02 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ kernel: PM: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x160 returns -110
Jul 09 15:42:02 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ kernel: PM: pci_pm_suspend(): hcd_pci_suspend+0x0/0x30 returns -110
Jul 09 15:42:02 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ kernel: PM: suspend_common(): xhci_pci_suspend+0x0/0x100 returns -110
Jul 09 15:42:02 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.2: WARN: xHC CMD_RUN timeout
Jul 09 15:42:02 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ kernel: wlo1: deauthenticating from 94:65:2d:07:2b:71 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Jul 09 15:42:02 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Jul 09 15:42:02 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.000 seconds) done.
Jul 09 15:42:02 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Jul 09 15:42:02 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Jul 09 15:42:02 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.007 seconds
Jul 09 15:42:02 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Jul 09 15:42:02 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ systemd-sleep[5293]: Suspending system...
Jul 09 15:42:02 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Jul 09 15:42:02 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Jul 09 15:42:01 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ NetworkManager[1030]: <info>  [1594289521.1328] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Jul 09 15:42:01 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ NetworkManager[1030]: <info>  [1594289521.1324] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 09 15:42:01 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ NetworkManager[1030]: <info>  [1594289521.1121] device (eno2): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 09 15:42:01 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ NetworkManager[1030]: <info>  [1594289521.1119] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Jul 09 15:42:01 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Jul 09 15:42:01 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Jul 09 15:42:01 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Jul 09 15:42:01 LAPTOP-RUL9M0JJ systemd-logind[1011]: Power key pressed.
```

I used the following command to unbind it:

```
echo 0000:01:00.2 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.2/driver/unbind
```

And now suspend is working properly.

`lspci -v` shows the following data for this device:

```
01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 10ff
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at a2000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [virtual] [size=256K]
    Memory at a2040000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [virtual] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b4] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
```

Does anyone have any idea what this device is? Also, please let me know if this is the right way to handle this problem.